# Multiple arduino slaves with one master computer that sends instructions for the actuators to work

Tags: arduino-uno, uart

I am in the middle of an automation project and suddenly after completing one stage of my assembly, I now need to scale it. So my computer which until now was sending data to only one arduino UNO can send to multiple arduino uno's, also I am seeking an advice, I am using up all the digital pins on my arduino Uno and this makes me think if I should upgrade to arduino mega or leave it the way it is.
The communication protocol I am using is UART which is done through USB from my computer to the board, so can I just use a USB hub to handle this issue?

Comment: If you’re sure that you won’t expand your project and need more pins, why upgrade? If you have lots of free analog pins you can use them as digital pins too.

Comment: Yes, if course you can use a USB hub to connect multiple Arduinos to your PC at once. If you need to upgrade to a mega depends on if you need more pins

Comment: Thank you so much I definitely not need more pins on one communication as the more the messy it gets thats why I tried sticking to Uno to the least, I would rather get multiple unos so troubleshooting doesn't become a challenge.